# SQL Query XML Issue

Tags: xml

I am having issues obtaining the value from the CultureString tag within the olapDatasource tag in the xml, specifically the value attribute in this example I should be returning 'CubeTwo' but to no avail.

I have tried select

> xml.value('declare namespace x="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-Resource"; declare
>   namespace f="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-LocalizableString";
>   (/x:SearchMetadata/Connection/SerializableServerConnectionInfo/OlapServerConnectionInfo/OlapDataSource/LocalizableString/CultureStrings/CultureString/@Value)[0]',
>   'nvarchar(max)')

from Resource

But I get NULL. Any Ideas how to return this value ?

```
<SearchMetadata xmlns="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-Resource">
  <Properties Id="fc124f36-45f4-4847-b7b6-01754e10bdc8" UniqueId="c270485a-3106-4dec-be77-127bfbf98f24" ResourceType="Analysis" Version="6.4.39306.17532" SystemResource="false" SolutionName="Solution.ZapTechnologyDevelopment.AXDiscreteManufacturing" Licensed="false" PolicyRoot="false">
    <DatabaseRowVersion>"AAAAAAABGVA="</DatabaseRowVersion>
    <Name DefaultCulture="en-US" DefaultCultureValue="Quick Ratio Trend">
      <CultureStrings xmlns="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-LocalizableString">
        <CultureString Culture="en-US" Value="Quick Ratio Trend" LowerValue="quick ratio trend" />
      </CultureStrings>
    </Name>
    <Created>2014-08-01T13:13:15.1449044+01:00</Created>
    <Modified>2014-08-01T12:37:36.9173669Z</Modified>
    <ModifiedBy Name="Schuster" UserName="ADMINIS-CMNLQS3\Schuster" Email="">
    </ModifiedBy>
    <Parent Id="6fc3df4f-0241-4db1-8b49-c8bea68e90cb" />
    <Policy Id="c00daeaa-0a98-4a02-b746-3253bcc47e51" />
    <PendingImportId xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p3:nil="true" />
    <ExtendedProperties TypeName="Zap.BI.Resources.CellSets.CellSetProperties, Zap.BI.Resources">
      <CellSetProperties>
        <DisplayChart>true</DisplayChart>
        <DisplayPivotTable>false</DisplayPivotTable>
      </CellSetProperties>
    </ExtendedProperties>
  </Properties>
  <ResourceReferences>
  </ResourceReferences>
  <Connection xmlns="">
    <SerializableServerConnectionInfo TypeName="Zap.BI.Resources.DataSources.OlapServerConnectionInfo, Zap.BI.Resources">
      <OlapServerConnectionInfo>
        <OlapDataSource ResourceTypeName="OlapDataSource" ReferenceType="Persisted" Id="{14131aa1-8223-40bd-ae7d-f035f9f09374}">
          <LocalizableString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DefaultCulture="en-US" DefaultCultureValue="CubeTwo">
            <CultureStrings xmlns="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-LocalizableString">
              <CultureString Culture="en-US" Value="CubeTwo" LowerValue="cubetwo" />
            </CultureStrings>
          </LocalizableString>
          <DisconnectedResourceOfOlapDataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
        </OlapDataSource>
      </OlapServerConnectionInfo>
    </SerializableServerConnectionInfo>
    <DatabaseName>Dynamics AX 2012R2 An</DatabaseName>
    <CubeName>Dynamics AX</CubeName>
    <ConfiguredCubeReference ResourceTypeName="ConfiguredCube" ReferenceType="Persisted" Id="{df13a7c0-2845-48b0-8a7e-ec65ffd57e4c}">
      <LocalizableString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DefaultCulture="en-US" DefaultCultureValue="Dynamics AX 2012">
        <CultureStrings xmlns="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-LocalizableString">
          <CultureString Culture="en-US" Value="Dynamics AX 2012" LowerValue="dynamics ax 2012" />
        </CultureStrings>
      </LocalizableString>
      <DisconnectedResourceOfConfiguredCube xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    </ConfiguredCubeReference>
    <PerspectiveId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</PerspectiveId>
  </Connection>
</SearchMetadata>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. If you look closely at your attempt, you'll see that you've declared but not *used* one of your namespaces. You need to use it twice. Also, the index should be `1`, not `0`:

```sql
select @x.value('declare namespace x="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-Resource";
declare namespace f="urn:Schemas-Zap-BI-LocalizableString";
(/x:SearchMetadata/Connection/SerializableServerConnectionInfo/OlapServerConnectionInfo/
OlapDataSource/LocalizableString/f:CultureStrings/f:CultureString/@Value)[1]',
'nvarchar(max)')
```

Result:

```
CubeTwo
```